# Can SVN be used to version .DOC/.XLS files without redundancy in storage?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, storage, redundancy

I currently use TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 to access files on an Apache server.  I was curious to know if SVN can be configured in some way so that several revisions of .DOC/.XLS files can be stored without redundancy.  IOW, if I check out a .DOC file, add 28 bytes of text to the filesize & check in the changes, the amount of file storage on the server only increases by ~28 bytes.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: SVN is designed to [work with binary files](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.forcvs.binary-and-trans.html), so DOC/XLS should present no problems.

Answer (score 1):

While Subversion does use a binary diffing algorithm to store any type of file, your repository will grow more than 28 bytes if you only change 28 characters in the file. It will be less than the full size of the file (in most cases - the "skip deltas" algorithm *does* occasionally store a full copy of the file for efficiency reasons in checking out).

That said, storage is cheap these days and if saving a few KB or even a few hundred KB) in storing a complete history of your documents presents a major financial obstacle, you may have larger issues to work out in your organization.

Comment: Thanks alroc!  I failed to mention that the entirety of the set of .XLS files that I will need to store is close to 1 GB, and available server space at my organization is becoming a highly scrutinized commodity.

Comment: 1GB is **minuscule** when you consider that storage is purchased in quantities measured by the terabyte. If people are scrutinizing to that degree, either they've got too much time on their hands or your organization is penny-pinching in the wrong places - the time people are spending worrying about this is more expensive (in terms of their salaries) than the cost of that storage.